# Stack some floated elements on top of each other without wrapper

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a responsive site that contains some elements that have the `float: left` css. For smaller screens, I want to move the second element beneath the first one.

HTML:

```
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    float: left;
}
```

Picture: Above the red line is the current layout, below it the desired layout for smaller screens. The size or alignment of the divs does not need to change.

[image: desired behaviour]

Can I achieve this effect without wrapping divs A and B in a new div?

Comment: Without wrapping you cannot.

Comment: You may wanna take a look at [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). I don't have enough knowledge to provide a full answer but I once had a similar need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:** You can use `clear:left` on the div B then use `translate-Y` to let the C div on top;

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: honeydew;  
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 36px;  
}

#a {
  float: left;
  background-color: tomato;  
}

#b {  
  float: left;
  clear:left;
  background-color: gold;  
}

#c {  
  float: left;
  background-color: skyblue; 
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div id=a>1.</div>
<div id=b>2.</div>
<div id=c>3.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sadly it only works if div C does not have `float: left` as well.

Comment: @KWeiss by using media queries you can remove the `float: left` property of C when the screen size is small enough

Comment: **updated** same result but now all divs with `float:left`

Comment: Now it only works if C is the same height as A. @PhazePhusion, thank you, but I still need them to float, just in a different layout.

Comment: So, as [GigiSan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2898163/gigisan) said, the solution for you is flex-box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you'd be interested in some **jQuery**, but let me provide a bit **rough example**, something like **structural programming** and could be surely cleaned up, but this allows you to add some classes and rearrange elements dynamically, without touching the HTML code at all.

```
<div class="first">A</div>
<div class="second">B</div>
<div class="third">C</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.first {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.second {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.third {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#left-row {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.need-wrapper-right {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  if ($(window).width() < 800) {
    $(".second").detach().insertAfter(".first");
    $(".first").addClass("need-wrapper-left");
    $(".second").addClass("need-wrapper-left");
    $(".third").addClass("need-wrapper-right");
    $(".need-wrapper-left").wrapAll("<div id='left-row'>");
    $(".second").detach().insertAfter(".first");
    $(".third").insertAfter($("#left-row"));
  }

});
```

Check the demo on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/bbirdme/pen/mPeOmw) (the code is set to rearrange elements below 800px). You can check the jQuery documentation about .detach(), addClass() and other functions.

**EDIT:** Also, you should use **media queries** so these CSS classes would apply only on lower resolutions.